# what does "Emperor lives on" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

Simply, I couldn't understand that sentence. I found that sentence on an image on twitter .

could you help ?

Comment: Without the context of the image, it's hard to imagine it means anything other than the literal meaning which is that the Emporer lives on (or in other words, the Emporer continues to live).

Comment: Could be an indirect allusion to: the Emperor's new clothes.

Answer (score 1):

[**Live on**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+on)

> To persist; endure: *Although The Beatles broke up decades ago, their music lives on.*

*thefreedictionary.com*

They are saying that although the person may be dead, his legacy is still persisting.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an awkward translation of

[The king is dead, long live the king!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_king_is_dead,_long_live_the_king!)

> The original phrase was translated from the French Le roi est mort, vive le roi !, which was first declared upon the accession to the French throne of Charles VII after the death of his father Charles VI in 1422. In France, the declaration was traditionally made by the duc d'Uzès, a senior peer of France, as soon as the coffin containing the remains of the previous king descended into the vault of Saint Denis Basilica. The phrase arose from the law of le mort saisit le vif—that the transfer of sovereignty occurs instantaneously upon the moment of death of the previous monarch. "The King is dead" is the announcement of a monarch who has just died. "Long live The King!" refers to the heir who immediately succeeds to a throne upon the death of the preceding monarch.